# How to execute multiple sql files in airflow using PostgresOperator?

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have multiple sql files in my sql folder. I am not sure how to execute all the sql files within a DAG?

```
  - dags
    - sql
      - dummy1.sql
      - dummy2.sql
```

For a single file, below code works

```
sql_insert= PostgresOperator(task_id='sql_insert',
                             postgres_conn_id='postgres_conn',
                             sql='sql/dummy1.sql')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a list

```
sql_insert= PostgresOperator(task_id='sql_insert',
                             postgres_conn_id='postgres_conn',
                             sql=['sql/dummy1.sql', 'sql/dummy2.sql'])
```

Or you can make it dynamic

```
import glob
sql_insert= PostgresOperator(task_id='sql_insert',
                             postgres_conn_id='postgres_conn',
                             sql=glob.glob("sql/*.sql")]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. the first solution is working but the dynamic one is not. it is showing the task is success but not inserting the data

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Javier Lopez Tomas' answer, in order to do this dynamically, you must make the path of the files relative to the `template_searchpath` you specify when initiating your DAG. `glob` returns the absolute paths of the files matching the pattern. You could augment with the following:

```
import glob
sql_insert= PostgresOperator(task_id='sql_insert',
                             postgres_conn_id='postgres_conn',
                             sql=[x.split(template_searchpath)[1] for x in glob.glob("sql/*.sql")]
```